# "S" key does not work in X11 (XQuartz)

Tags: keyboard, x11, xquartz

The <kbd>S</kbd> key seems to be mapped to an incorrect value in XQuartz for me.  I am running OS X 10.7.5 and XQuartz 2.7.4 (xorg-server 1.13.0).  The problem also occurs in X11.app (XQuartz 2.6.5, xorg-server 1.10.6).  I am also running Homebrew  0.9.4, if that makes a difference.

Pressing <kbd>S</kbd> in X has never worked correctly for me.  In most applications in X, pressing <kbd>S</kbd> has no effect.  It may actually be mapped to a meta-key, because pressing <kbd>S</kbd> in some contexts (*e.g.*, in most save dialogs) seems to trigger button hotkeys.  If I copy the "s" character from within a native Cocoa application and then paste it into an X application, that works fine.

**Update:** `xev` reports the following when <kbd>S</kbd> is pressed:

```
KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
    root 0x281, subw 0x0, time 2057519943, (138,-10), root:(158,32),
    state 0x0, keycode 9 (keysym 0xff1b, Escape), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) "
mbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) "
FilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
    root 0x281, subw 0x0, time 2057520022, (138,-10), root:(158,32),
    state 0x0, keycode 9 (keysym 0xff1b, Escape), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) "
FilterEvent returns: False
```

**Update 2:** `xmodmap` reports:

```
shift       Shift_L (0x40),  Shift_R (0x44)
lock      
control     Control_L (0x41),  Control_L (0x43),  Control_R (0x46)
mod1        Mode_switch (0x42),  Mode_switch (0x45)
mod2        Meta_L (0x3f),  Meta_R (0x47)
mod3      
mod4      
mod5
```

Comment: What does `xev` report when you press `S`?

Comment: @lhf: I just updated the question with the result.

Comment: What does `xmodmap -pke` report?

Comment: Updated the question with `xmodmap` output.

Comment: Use the `-pke` option and look at the entry for  keycode 9: `xmodmap -pke| grep ' 9 ='`.

Comment: `keycode   9 = Escape U203D Escape U203`

Comment: There you go. `s` is `Escape`. I don't know how it got be like this. But you may want to reset the map. Try `setxkbmap -layout us` as recommended by http://askubuntu.com/questions/29603/how-do-i-clear-xmodmap-settings.

Comment: Ah, that may be part of the problem: `setxkbmap -layout us` returns `Error loading new keyboard description`!  By the way, this is a fresh install of X11 on a new MacBook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `s` has been mapped to Escape.

I don't know how it got be like this. I also don't know how to reset the map, given that `setxkbmap -layout us` (recommended by https://askubuntu.com/questions/29603/how-do-i-clear-xmodmap-settings) does not work. (It doesn't work for me either.)

So, as a last resort, if the only problem is `s`, then try

```
xmodmap -e "keycode   9 = s S ssharp Iacute"
```

Comment: No idea what caused this either, but your xmodmap command fixed the problem.  If no one else responds with the root cause in the next day or so, I'll mark your answer as accepted.  Thanks!

Comment: @ESultanik, note that this is not a permanent solution: you'll have to  do this every time you start the X server, if the problem is persistent. In this case, look in your X11 init files and check that none of them is changing the map.